# In an iframe based website, how to load all iframes in a new window after user clicks on a link within one iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, iframe, browser

I am having a problem with an iframe (Java servlets) based website which looks somewhat like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    
<iframe id="top" name="top" src="$link.setAction('top').relative()"></iframe>

<iframe id="content" name="content" src="$link.setAction('content').relative()"></iframe>

<iframe id="footer" name="footer" src="$link.setAction('footer').relative()"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Because each of the iframes is a standalone page, if a user decides to open a link from within any of the iframes, the page that is loaded in a new window or tab looks broken as it is only one part of the whole website.

I was wondering if there is a way to detect whether the user chose "open in a new tab" or "open in the new window" from the browser. Then, I would have to make sure that after this happens, all the iframes are loaded in a new window.

Let me know if there is a better solution, as well.

Comment: Why you need to do that? You will send a different rendered iframe in each case?

Comment: The application that I am working with has been built some time ago and somebody decided to use **frameset** which is not supported in HTML5. Therefore, we changed it to **iframes**. And the problem I just described in a comment below: "if somebody decides to use the right-click context menu and choose "open link in a new window", only the iframe from which the link comes will be opened. For example if I try to open a link from the **content** iframe, only this iframe without the **top** and **footer** will be loaded in the new window, so the page will look broken."

Answer (score 1):

Use the **target** attribute to solve your problem when user is navigating through the iframes.

Your iframes are already named **top**, **content**, and **footer**. You can also place the three iframes inside of a parent iframe, which you can then name something like **main_iframe**.

Then for your links, specify the name of the iframe you want them to open in using the target attribute.

```
<a href="top.html" target="top">Example link inside the top frame which opens only in top frame</a>
<a href="content.html" target="content">Example link inside the content frame</a>
<a href="bottom.html" target="bottom">Example link inside the bottom frame</a>

<a href="main.html" target="main_iframe">Example link which opens in the parent frame</a>
```

You can then disable the right click event using Javascript **oncontextmenu**:

```
    window.oncontextmenu = function() {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not solve my problem. I am already using the **target** attribute to navigate through the application. However, if somebody decides to use the right-click context menu and choose "open link in a new window", only the iframe from which the link comes will be opened. For example if I try to open a link from the **content** iframe, only this iframe without the **top** and **footer** will be loaded in the new window, so the page will look broken.